# Self signed certificate inside local network for development

Tags: java, android, ssl, ssl-certificate, liferay

I'm working with a liferay application that is hosted on a machine at 192.168.1.50:8443 with a self signed certificate (keystore was added to tomcat).
I now want to connect the API to an android app. This connection works in production, but I can't make it work in my local environment, even after accepting the certificate in chrome, and installing it to the android device, it is detected but gives me this error:

```
SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname 192.168.1.50 not verified
```

But then it prints out the certificate being used and shows CN:192.168.1.50 and every parameter exactly as I set it. Can anyone give me some pointers of where to go from here? I have already tried everything I can find including injecting customized socket factories, hostname verifiers and SSL contexts.

Any help is appreciated, even if it is a way to trust all certificates I'll take it, I don't care about security, I just need this for development.

Comment: Chrome (or any modern browser for that matter) doesn't check the Common Name.  You need to add the IP address as an entry in the Subject Alternative Name extension of your self-signed certificate.

Comment: Does android use a Truststore?  Is the self-signed certificate in a new Truststore and is your android app pointing to that new Truststore file?

Comment: @garethTheRed Regenerated the certificates and set the Subject Alternative Name as IP:192.168.1.50 and it worked! Thank you so much!